# First expierences with struct. Why is this output happening?

Tags: c, struct

This is my first time using structs, I can`t understand why this output is happening, can someone explain it to me and tell what I am doing wrong?

```
struct letters {
        const char BIG[26];
        const char SMALL[26];
};
struct letters abc = { .BIG = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", .SMALL = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };
printf("%s", abc.BIG);
```

The output is:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Obviously what I want is to have the big letters in BIG and the small ones in SMALL. I tried to print abc.SMALL, it is filled correctly.

why is abc.BIG filled with both small and big letters?

Comment: There is no space for '\0' at the `BIG` `struct element`.
Quick fix - `const char BIG[27];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BIG` and `SMALL` have space for exactly 26 letters. But `printf` expects a `char *` with a `'\0'` at the end, which would mean the string needs space for 27 characters. As there is no space for the terminating-null the compiler doesn't put one in `BIG` or `SMALL` (even though the string constants do have one).

Therefore `printf` doesn't know where the string `BIG` ends and ends up printing `SMALL` as well.

Change `BIG` and `SMALL` to have space for `[27]` characters:

```
struct letters{
    const char BIG[27];
    const char SMALL[27];
};
```

Comment: You're welcome. It indeed seems a bit sneaky that the compiler silently truncates the string constants when the target array isn't big enough.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a `\0` to mark the end of strings because `BIG` and `SMALL` can only store 26 characters. Increase the size of `BIG` and `SMALL` like this:

```
const char BIG[27];
const char SMALL[27];
```

Since, `BIG` and `SMALL` are stored contiguously in the memory and there is nothing to tell the end of `BIG` and the start of `SMALL`, you are getting the lumped output.